Contour shading: how to shade only the positive contours?
termTwo[\[Kappa]_,\[Theta]_,\[Alpha]_,A_]:=Sum[((1+A^2)Cos[m \[Theta]](Sin[(m \[Kappa])/2])^2)/m^(1+\[Alpha]), {m, 1, 200}];
ContourPlot[(termTwo[\[Kappa], \[Theta], \[Alpha], 
    A]) /. {\[Theta] -> \[Pi]/6, A -> 0.3}, {\[Kappa], 
  0, \[Pi]}, {\[Alpha], 0, 5}, 
 FrameLabel -> {Style["\[Kappa]", 16, Bold], 
   Style["\[Alpha]", 16, Bold]}, FrameStyle -> Thick, 
 PlotLegends -> Automatic]

The above code defines a function and plots it's contours per some varied parameters. I am interested only where the function is positive. How do I specify those contours?

Attempt:
ContourPlot[(termTwo[\[Kappa], \[Theta], \[Alpha], 
    A]) /. {\[Theta] -> \[Pi]/6, A -> 0.3}, {\[Kappa], 
  0, \[Pi]}, {\[Alpha], 0, 5}, 
 FrameLabel -> {Style["\[Kappa]", 16, Bold], 
   Style["\[Alpha]", 16, Bold]}, FrameStyle -> Thick, 
 PlotLegends -> Automatic, Contours -> {0}, 
 ContourShading -> {{Opacity[.5], ColorData[97][1]}, None}]

The above code does the opposite! It shows only where the function is negative.

"The above code does the opposite!" -- Did you try reversing the ContourShading?

@MichaelE2 oops...

@MichaelE2 Should I delete the question? With the reverse shading (duh) it works as desired.

Explanation: Suppose contours are drawn a numerical levels L1, L2, etc. in increasing order. In your case, you have just one, L1 = 0. Anyway, in general, ContourShading -> {dir1, dir2,...} means the shading and level curves are done in the order dir1, L1, dir2, L2, dir3...., with the directives (dir1 etc.) cycling around if there are more levels than directives.

I suppose you can delete the Q. Though the site seems more tolerant of things explained in the documentation than it was a few years ago.

@MichaelE2 I think your comment could be an Answer.

Okay. Done. Thanks.

Answer: Try reversing the ContourShading (using Directive instead of a list sometimes prevents mis-parsing by *Plot commands):
ContourShading -> {None, Directive[Opacity[.5], ColorData[97][1]]}

Explanation: Suppose contours are drawn a numerical levels L1, L2, etc. in increasing order. In your case, you have just one, L1 = 0. Anyway, in general, ContourShading -> {dir1, dir2,...} means the shading and level curves are done in the order dir1, L1, dir2, L2, dir3...., with the directives (dir1 etc.) cycling around if there are more levels that directives.

+1 Directive[Opacity[.5], ColorData[97][1]] can be simplified to Opacity[.5, ColorData[97][1]]
